# TYPO3 6.1 FAL: How to use PublicUrl for images in RTE?

Tags: amazon-s3, typo3, typo3-6.1.x

I'm using TYPO3 6.1 with an Amazon S3 Driver for the File Abstraction Layer.
This driver returns for every file a "PublicURL" like this: `https://MYBUCKET.s3.amazonaws.com/filename`.

When i use the "Image Only" content element, the image is correctly embedded with the Amazon URL. But when I use the text element and insert the image with the RTE, the image is copied to the local file system in `typo3temp` and renamed to `fal-tempfile-XYZ`.
Is it possible to configure the RTE, so that the Amazon URL are used? My goal is to output all images via the Amazon CDN.

In both cases I have previously uploaded the picture via the TYPO3 File Manger, and only selected it in the content element later.
I haven't used the "Magic" mode.

Answer (score 0):

The [Documentation mentions](http://wiki.typo3.org/File_Abstraction_Layer#Default_Upload_Folder_for_the_RTE) the FAL should be configured for each backend user via TSconfig:

```
options.defaultUploadFolder = 1:/mypics/
```

Comment: Does not work. The images are also already uploaded, it should only be selected. I do not want extra copies.

Answer (score 0):

There is a new Extension in TYPO3 CMS TER "aus_driver_amazon_s3" which supports a TYPO3 CDN FAL Driver for Amazon S3 (requires TYPO3 6.2)

German blog post: [TYPO3 CDN](http://www.andersundsehr.com/blog/technik/typo3-performance-optimierung-durch-cdn) with Amazon S3